# SSL Handshakes on connection setup

Tags: ssl, web, browser, https

When I test my website performance I noticed SSL handshakes are happening as part of connection setup. I understand the first request (of the page) needs the full SSL handshake.

But, if you notice from the pingdom test, only certain other resources are doing the SSL handshake. The remaining requests in the page do not.

Can someone please explain the logic behind this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources that are loaded via HTTPS will have their own SSL handshake if new TCP connections are used to retrieve them. If HTTP keep-alives are used, resources on the same server may be retrieved using existing connections.  Resources retrieved via HTTP instead of HTTPS, or reside on different servers/domains, will have to use separate connections.

Your test results are fairly useless for diagnosing this, without knowing *which* resources are being retrieved, *where* they are being retrieved from, and *what protocol* they are being retrieved with.

Comment: All the resources point to the same domain. Its fully SSL (https). And the server is node.js

Comment: Those factors do not eliminate the possibility that separate TCP connections, and thus separate SSL handshakes, are being used to retrieve them. Even with HTTP keep-alives, HTTP pipelining, etc, if the page is loading lots of resources, it may have to use multiple connections.  Without actually seeing the HTML itself, there is no way for anyone here to tell you what is actually happening.

Comment: OK, But why would other resources not do even an abbreviated SSL handshake? (My server supports SSL session resumption). Isn't is true that every request made will have a SSL handshake?

Comment: No, if TCP connections are being reused for multiple requests to the same server (via HTTP keep-alives).  An SSL handshake is only needed when creating a new connection.  Multiple connections cannot use the same SSL session at the same time.  But a connection can create a session, disconnect, and then a new connection can pick up the previous session (if both client and server are coded to allow that).

Comment: @user3658423 Multiple connections most certainly *can* use the same SSL session at the same time. That's one of the things they are for. Any new connection can reuse a session, if it is still valid.